How is radiation emitted from a small hole in a box, if the hole is small enough to prevent radiation from escaping in the first place?
So I totally understand how a hole in a box works as a good approximation for a perfect absorber of all incident radiation (a black body). However, a black body is also a perfect emitter of radiation and this radiation from the hole has been observed and studied using an IR camera.
My question is, where is this radiation coming from? I know that the hole itself is treated as the blackbody, not the cavity, therefore the radiation must be spontaneously emitted by the hole, which consists of nothing but a few air molecules. So that's not possible.
If the radiation, then, is coming from the cavity and not the hole, how is it escaping through the hole when we have already established that the it is small enough to prevent any outgoing radiations. The thermal radiation emitted by the inner walls of the box would reflect and get absorbed by the walls themselves, so how do they reach the hole.
And even if they do escape from the hole, the rate of emitted radiation would nowhere be the same  as the rate of incident radiation which the hole absorbs. So how will the hole be a good approximation of a black body.
I know that several studies and experiments have already been made on the box serving as a blackbody, so there must be something wrong with my thought process and I hope someone could kindly clarify where I went wrong.

You seem confused (which is why you asked the question). The interior of the cavity is in thermal equilibrium with itself sending a range of photons flying around in all directions. The hole lets just a little bit of that equilibrated light out, little enough not to significantly impact the thermal equilibrium yet enough to measure the properties of.

Yes, I was confused as to how the interior of the cavity was able to emit radiation from the hole when a ray emitted from an inner wall is also equally likely to reflect and get absorbed by the wall again.


where is this radiation coming from?

It comes from the interior surfaces of the walls of the box.

I know that the hole itself is treated as the blackbody

Yes, treated as. The hole isn't really the source of the radiation, but we can pretend that the rays—which actually are coming through the hole from inside the box—came from an imaginary black surface that exactly fits in the hole.

how is it escaping through the hole when we have already established that the it is small enough to prevent any outgoing radiations.

That doesn't make any sense. Who told you that the hole was too small to allow any radiation to escape?
The purpose of the box-and-hole apparatus is that most of the light rays that enter through the hole and are reflected by the interior surfaces will not be reflected back out because the hole is a relatively small target. Most of the reflected light rays will hit the interior walls again, and again,... until they finally are absorbed.

Well, the emitted thermal radiation is also a light ray right? I imagined a ray exiting an inner wall struggling to find the hole to exit from. Won't it keep bouncing around on the inner walls until it too gets absorbed..? If this is true, then the number of rays the hole emits will just be a fraction of the number of incident rays. That is why I am still confused.

@LordQuasimoto, Yes. Only a small fraction of the photons that bounce around inside the box will find the hole and escape. But, only a small fraction of that small fraction will be photons that scattered one or more times before entering the box through the hole from outside.
